# pgfplots, groupplot: How to read out and set plot-lengths

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, groupplots

I set `width=33mm` in a groupplot. How is this width to understand? 
I thought it has to be: "graph width" + label distance, but it seems to be another value. 
How can I read out the label distance in a groupplot?

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\begin{groupplot}[group style={group size={2 by 2,},
horizontal sep=22mm, %vertical sep=1cm,
}, 
width=33mm,
y tick label style={draw},
ylabel style={draw},
]
\nextgroupplot[title={1}, ylabel=ylabel]
\addplot[]{x};
\nextgroupplot[title={2}, ylabel=ylabel]
\addplot[]{2*x};
\end{groupplot}

\draw[red, very thick] (group c1r1.south east) -- +(-33mm,0) node[midway, above, fill=yellow]{33mm}; 

% Does not work
%\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\ttt{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/group/label distance}}
%\node[fill=yellow]{\ttt};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you add `scale only axis`, the specified width is the width of the axis. Otherwise, the width of the axis becomes 33mm-45pt (in this case), where the 45pt is a hardcoded length to make room for labels.

Comment: Ah ok, I think that helps.